# Why is my MySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF not working?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, timedelta

Hello I have a stored timestamp "oldtime" and I want to get the difference from the current time, but it is not working and not throwing any errors either so Im at a lost.

```
$timediff = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, %s, NOW())", GetSQLValueString($oldtime, "text")), $DBName) or die (mysql_error());

$diff = mysql_fetch_assoc($timediff);

echo '<script>console.log("time diff:'.$diff[0].'");</script>';

.$diff. results in "time diff:Array"

.$diff[0]. results in "time diff: "

.$timediff. results in "time diff:Resource id #6"
```

Comment: What do you get? Please describe.

Comment: see edit, i provided the console out put when changing what it echo's

Comment: Not sure how to or if I can, but i don't think that edit should be approved since the last three lines are not exactly code, just a sniper with my own words on what it results

Comment: Simply re-edit it and reformat! why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_fetch_assoc by default returns an array indexed by column name, rather than column number.

The column name will be literally the function string, something like

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(table.col1, NOW())
```

Easier way here would be to fetch by column number instead using either  mysql_fetch_row, or mysql_fetch_array

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

An alternative would be to use some array function to extract the elements without the name, see:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php